# WPF Slider AutoToolTip visible on hover

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

By default the AutoToolTip only shows up when the users click the thumb, but I want to be able to show it as soon as the mouse is over the thumb (without clicking). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I forgot about this question. [I solved it myself](http://wpfdude.blogspot.com/2010/07/rule-of-thumb-sliders-thumb.html).

Thanks!

Comment: Your link is broken, Can you add the answer to your question here?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this simple code, and when mouse is over slider(all parts) tool-tip is shown Quickly.

```
<Slider Width="100"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="HI ITS ME" />
```

So I guess you have use template for your slider or use tooltip-service kind which can be disable default setting!
Test that, I hope help you
Regards Rev